# formatting a string in java

Tags: java

I would like to know how to provide a formatting capabilities that enable the user  to specify the number of digits of precision to the right of a decimal number. so instead of using the classical formatting .2f or .3f etc.. I want the user to be able to enter the precision of the decimal number.

i have a code written as follows

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
int precision = input.nextInt();

addNumbers.numberRepresentaiton(int precision);
```

The method is defined as below

```
private String numberRepresentation(int precision)
{
    return String.format("%.precisionf", add);
}
```

executing the above results in conversion formatting error.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: nice question, I was curious too!

Comment: Yeahh I know Adel !! I was thinking of it for about 10 minutes and I was not thinking of the concatenation as a solution to it. anyhow problem solved :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private String numberRepresentation(int precision)
{
    return String.format("%." + precision + "f", add);
}
```

You have to concatenate the format string - the `Formatter` can't detect the variable name automagically ;)

Comment: Thank you Andreas, it works and the it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
return String.format("%." + precision + "f", add);
```

Comment: Thank you icyrock for the asnwer!!